# How to screen cast with anycast dongle from Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, display, screencast

I have an anycast dongle and Ubuntu laptop. I want to screencast my screen. How to achieve this?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BSAvoruQXEc

Comment: Thanks. But, this for mobiles. I am looking for laptop. Especially for Ubuntu OS

Comment: It's for WiFi isn't it? I didn't think it mattered what device.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?